# Putting an RCA splitter on my receiver for two subwoofers

Tags: audio, rca, av-receiver

Here is a pretty basic question for some. I have an Onkyo tx ds 494 ( she's a little outdated). On the back of it there is a subwoofer pre out. I am a bass freak and always have to have more so I put a splitter on it. The question is, is that an ok thing to do to add two subwoofers, or will it fry the receiver.

Anything will help

Comment: What is the reason for doing so?

Comment: are the subwoofers powered on unpowered?

Comment: In adding moré bass. And yes they are powered. They came with an amp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my personal experience with audio jacks (not specifically subwoofer) if you simply split the cable into 2 output, the output (volume) on each cable are halved (or part thereof) so my current guess is that your subwoofer will just get output half of the volume.

I guess as long as your Onkyo output is not doubled to gain the loss in volume, you should be fine.. but you probably know better about audio than me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm wondering if they would be halved because they are both powered subwoofers

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not do any harm to the receiver. You have to rely on speaker resistance. Try to connect speaker with correct resistance.

Comment: What do you mean by resistance

Comment: Please read this article about [resistance](http://www.marktaw.com/recording/Electronics/OhmsAmpsandSpeakers.html). You should be aware of connecting a speaker with matching resistance to an output of any audio devices. You can find the value of resistance in Ohms on speakers.